# Can't represent all fields of a serialized ManyToMany through model with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django and Django Rest Framework to represent a 'BaseRecipe' model. This model has a M2M field to represent the ingredients of that recipe. That M2M field relates a 'Product' object with the 'BaseRecipe' object and extends that two models with another field to represent the 'quantity'. I'm trying to retrieve a list of those ingredients in the BaseRecipeSerializer, but only the id's are returned.

Any ideas why?

Thank you in advance!

My models.py:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255, help_text=_('Product name'))
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, blank=True, related_name='supplier_products', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    serial_no = models.CharField(_('Serial number'), max_length=50, blank=True,
                                 help_text=_('Product serial number. Max 50 characters.'))
    allergens = models.ManyToManyField(Allergen, blank=True, related_name='product_allergens')
    description = models.TextField(_('Description'), blank=True, help_text=_('Additional product information.'))
    is_vegan = models.BooleanField(_('Vegan'), default=False)
    is_halal = models.BooleanField(_('Halal'), default=False)
    format_container = models.CharField(_('Format container'), max_length=6, choices=CONTAINERS, blank=True,
                                        help_text=_('Package format'))
    format_quantity = models.DecimalField(_('Format quantity'), blank=True, null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=3,
                                          help_text=_('Format quantity sell'))
    format_unit = models.CharField(_('Format unit'), max_length=6, choices=UNITS, blank=True)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(_('Quantity'), blank=True, null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=3,
                                   help_text=_('Quantity per unit provided'))
    type = models.CharField(_('Type'), max_length=255, help_text=_('Type'), blank=True)
    unit = models.CharField(_('Unit'), max_length=6, choices=UNITS)
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(_('Unit price'), blank=True, null=True, max_digits=9, decimal_places=3)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name', ]

    @property
    def price(self) -> Decimal:
        return self.quantity * self.unit_price

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class BaseRecipe(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_base_recipes')
    restaurant = models.ForeignKey(Restaurant, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                                   related_name='restaurant_base_recipes')
    title = models.CharField(_('Base recipe title'), max_length=255, help_text=_('Base recipe. Example: Chicken broth'),
                             blank=True)
    elaboration = models.TextField(_('Elaboration'), blank=True, help_text=_('Base recipe making instructions.'))
    quantity = models.DecimalField(_('Quantity'), max_digits=9, decimal_places=3,
                                   help_text=_('Quantity produced with this recipe (after cooking). '))
    unit = models.CharField(_('Unit'), max_length=6, choices=UNITS)
    expiry_date = models.DateField(_('Expiry date'), help_text=_('Last day product is safe to consume.'))
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Product, through='IngredientBaseRecipe', related_name='base_recipe_ingredients')
    image = models.ImageField(_('Picture'), upload_to=get_picture_path, blank=True, null=True)
    exhausted = models.BooleanField(_('Exhausted'), default=False, help_text=_('If it\'s needed to produce more.'))
    next_batch_date = models.DateField(_('Next batch date'), blank=True,
                                       help_text=_('When it\'s necessary to prepare more of this base recipe.'))
    storage = models.CharField(_('Storage'), max_length=12, choices=STORAGE_METHODS, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    @property
    def cost(self) -> Decimal:
        return sum([ingredient.cost for ingredient in self.ingredients.all()])

    @property
    def allergens(self):
        allergens_ids = IngredientBaseRecipe.objects.filter(base_recipe=self).values_list('product__allergens',
                                                                                          flat=True)
        allergens = Allergen.objects.filter(id__in=allergens_ids)
        return allergens

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title


class IngredientBaseRecipe(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    base_recipe = models.ForeignKey(BaseRecipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product_quantity = models.DecimalField(_('Product quantity'), max_digits=9, decimal_places=3, default=0.0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    @property
    def allergens(self):
        return self.product.allergens.all()

    @property
    def cost(self) -> Decimal:
        return self.quantity * self.product.unit_price

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

serializer.py:

```py
class SimpleProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'name', ]


class IngredientBaseRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # product_name = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='product.name')
    product = SimpleProductSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = IngredientBaseRecipe
        exclude = ['base_recipe', ]


class BaseRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientBaseRecipeSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    allergens = AllergenSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    cost = serializers.FloatField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BaseRecipe
        fields = '__all__'
```

Result:

```json
{
    "count": 3,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 5,
            "ingredients": [
                {
                    "id": 1
                },
                {
                    "id": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 3
                }
            ],
            "allergens": [
                {
                    "id": 9,
                    "name": "Celery",
                    "icon": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 12,
                    "name": "Sulphites",
                    "icon": null
                }
            ],
            "title": "Tipical Spanish",
            "elaboration": "No se tio.",
            "quantity": "23232.000",
            "unit": "l",
            "expiry_date": "2021-02-28",
            "image": null,
            "exhausted": false,
            "next_batch_date": "2021-03-01",
            "storage": "freezer",
            "user": 1,
            "restaurant": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "ingredients": [],
            "allergens": [],
            "cost": 0.0,
            "title": "Chicken broth",
            "elaboration": "One, two, three.",
            "quantity": "45.000",
            "unit": "l",
            "expiry_date": "2021-02-28",
            "image": null,
            "exhausted": false,
            "next_batch_date": "2021-03-01",
            "storage": "freezer",
            "user": 1,
            "restaurant": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BaseRecipe.ingredients` will return a queryset of `Product` instances but you are passing them to the `IngredientBaseRecipeSerializer`. You need to change the `source` for this field so that you pass the related `IngredientBaseRecipe` instances to this field

```
class BaseRecipeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ingredients = IngredientBaseRecipeSerializer(
        many=True,
        read_only=True,
        source='ingredientbaserecipe_set'
    )
    ...
```